# Flutter doctor - Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-doctor

I just updated my Flutter form  3.5.0-12.0.pre.168 to 3.6.0-1.0.pre.35 on the master channel.
Im on the master channel because on the stable channel I have troubles with keyboard inputs. But that shouldn't have to do anything with this "problem". Actually is it not a real problem, because everything is still working.
Only the Flutter doctor has a new check that I didn't had before or didn't notice.
It's checking now the Windows Version. But on my computer it is't able to check it.
I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.6.0-1.0.pre.35, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251], locale de-DE)
[X] Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

_

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.6.0-1.0.pre.35 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c021d9177c (56 minutes ago) • 2022-11-10 23:36:02 -0800
Engine • revision 19ead2834a
Tools • Dart 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-388.0.dev) • DevTools 2.19.0
```

Comment: Have you considered that there's a bug in the code since the version you are using is still pre-alpha? Raise an issue on the GitHub page.

Comment: I did: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117890

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was an operation language problem. On English Windows versions the issue didn't appear. On almost every other language, in my case German it appeared though. This issue has been repaired on the master channel, see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117890).

Answer (score 13):

Write in your windows prompt o Powershell:

```
C:\>flutter upgrade
C:\>flutter channel master
C:\>flutter doctor -v
```

Comment: resolve problem

Comment: This fix is misleading. While it works you also change the version in use from stable to a development version which is not recommended when actively using flutter for development.  See @F.M. answer for details. To return to stable version run `flutter channel stable`. We need to wait until the fix is released.

Answer (score 2):

I removed flutter SDK and installed latest SDK then this problem was solved.
Don't forget to set the path of environment.

Deleting SDK took so much times... If you couldn't remove it, just reboot PC.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my channel to master from stable

c:\src\flutter>flutter channel

Flutter channels:

master

main

beta

- stable

so i write : flutter channel master

after that  : flutter doctor

and it was worked..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

flutter channel master # Switch to the master channel
flutter upgrade # Upgrade to the master version which includes the fix

Comment: Hey @Ibrahim, your answer is saying the same as the accepted answer and the other comments.
It is not good practice to 'just' switch to other channels. The 'stable' channel should be the channel on that you work if you develop for reallife production apps. 
This issue is not a big problem and can be ignored. So it is better to stay on the stable channel.
Just changing the channel to 'master' or even worth to other channels is only recommended if you know what is going on on this channels. Most time they are experimental and have their own issues. We should wait till it got fixed for stable.