# Flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Bad state: Instance of 'NotifyingLogger' has no ancestor delegate of type AppRunLogger"

Tags: flutter

I getting this problem when I try to run a flutter project in the VSCode, I can run the same program without problems in the android studio, but not in VSCcode.

Command: `Flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22621.1413], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.7.10 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4b12645012 (3 days ago), 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
    • Engine revision ec975089ac
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[X] Windows Version (Unable to confirm if installed Windows version is 10 or greater)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-33-ext5, build-tools 33.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33516.290
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] VS Code (version 1.77.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Vinicius\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22621.1413]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.147
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.62

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I use:

- Windows 11 Pro
- Version 22H2
- Installed on 29/‎11/‎2022
- Compiler 22621.1413
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22639.1000.0

Comment: Do have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399911/flutter-doctor-windows-version-unable-to-confirm-if-installed-windows-version), it might be helpful 